# Querying data by joining two resources

Tags: sparql, rdf

I have 2 RDF resources, one for decoration and other for time. All decorations have a begin and end date. A resource of decoration has a property whose will will be a link to a resource of type time.

I need to retrieve details of a decoration and instead of link to another resource as value for begin and end date, I want to get a value from a property of the linked resource.

My data looks something like this,

```
##
decoration:2
    rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual, :Decoration ;
    :id 2 ;
    :name "Major"^^xsd:string ;
    :abbreviation "SA"^^xsd:string ;
    time:hasBeginning decoration:decoration_start_2 ;
    time:hasEnd decoration:decoration_end_2 ;
    rdfs:label "Major" .

decoration:decoration_end_2
    rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual, time:Instant ;
    time:inXSDDate "1945-12-31"^^xsd:date .

decoration:decoration_start_2
    rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual, time:Instant ;
     time:inXSDDate "1931-01-01"^^xsd:date .

##
```

And my current query looks like this without the JOIN,

```
prefix dc: <https://www.w3.org/data/>
prefix time: <http://www.w3.org/2006/time#>

select ?subject ?name ?abbreviation ?id ?begin ?end
where {
  ?subject 
  dc:name ?name ;
  dc:abbreviation ?abbreviation; 
  dc:id ?id ; 
  time:hasBeginning ?begin; 
  time:hasEnd ?end;
}
```

The current output is

```
subject                                 name        abbreviation    id  begin                                                   end 

https://www.w3.org/data/decoration/1    Colonel     Nürnberg        1   https://www.w3.org/data/decoration/decoration_start_1   https://www.w3.org/data/decoration/decoration_end_1 
https://www.w3.org/data/decoration/2    Major       SA              2   https://www.w3.org/data/decoration/decoration_start_2   https://www.w3.org/data/decoration/decoration_end_2
```

I need to fetch the values for begin and end instead of resource links (Eg: For the second row I need the values "1945-12-31" and "1931-01-01" for begin and end dates respectively).

Comment: just follow the path of your RDF data: `time:hasBeginning ?beginEntity . ?beginEntity time:inXSDDate ?begin . time:hasEnd ?endEntity . ?endEntity time:inXSDDate ?end .`

Comment: It didn't work for me. After changing the query it does not give any results. The output has zero rows.

Comment: just to make clear. I just gave you the idea, the syntax has to be fixed in order to fit the query.

Comment: `select ?subject ?name ?abbreviation ?id ?begin ?end
where {
  ?subject 
  dc:name ?name ;
  dc:abbreviation ?abbreviation; 
  dc:id ?id ; 
  time:hasBeginning ?beginEntity . ?beginEntity time:inXSDDate ?begin .
  ?subject time:hasEnd ?endEntity . ?endEntity time:inXSDDate ?end .
}` - it has to work, otherwise you data is not what shown here, or I'm doing something stupid

Comment: Thanks it worked. I had missed ?subject in the middle.

Comment: ok, but then you should have gotten a syntax error